# Cannot find where image is located in header - Developer Tools?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site that I took over from another developer, but I am having serious difficulty finding the image that is prepended onto the top nav bar.  In the menu, I can only see all the individual dropdown buttons, but don't see any image.  Any idea where this would be located?  Also, are there any developer tools like ctrl-shift-j in chrome where I could click on the image and it would show me it's location in a wordpress file?  Thanks.

Comment: try header.php in the wp-content/themes/your-theme folder, on some themes you can upload in backend so it might be in admin somewhere. F12 for dev tools in chrome, but that won't tell you what wordpress file it's in.

Comment: I don't see the wp-content folder.  I am going from myurl.com/wp-admin/themes.php at the moment..